# Python code executing SQLite query twice against database

Tags: python, sqlite

I am struggling to understand why my code is producing the query output twice when accessing my database. Essentially I want my query to look up if todays date is present in the database and compare it to the booked_time date part as part of the recorded timestamp. If that is present print that record. As you can see below I encounter a "double output"

```
from flask import request
import sqlite3

def read_query(query):
    con = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
    cur = con.cursor()

    cur.execute(query)
    result = cur.fetchall()
    return result


q1 = """
SELECT email,booked_time,strftime('%Y-%m-%d',booked_time) as 'date'
FROM bookings
WHERE date = DATE('2023-09-04');
"""

print(read_query(q1))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
devbox:~/web_app_project$ python3 schedule.py 
[('someemail@gmail.com', '2023-09-04 10:00:00', '2023-09-04')]
[('someemail@gmail.com', '2023-09-04 10:00:00', '2023-09-04')]
```

I have tried remedying this with con.commit() and con.close() methods I get the same result. I have tried rewriting using the "with" context manager and still get a double output. Has anyone got a solution for this? I am expecting only one record to appear.

As part of @Daviids help troubleshooting:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import sqlite3 as sql

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/process', methods=['POST'])
def process():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.form['name']
        email = request.form['email']
        date = request.form['date']
        hour = request.form['hour']
        minutes = request.form['minutes']

        booked_time = (f"{date} {hour}:{minutes}:00")
        with sql.connect("database.db") as con:
            cur = con.cursor()
            cur.execute(
                "INSERT INTO bookings (name, email, booked_time) VALUES (?, ?, ?)",
                (name, email, booked_time))
            con.commit()
            msg = "Record successfully added"
    return msg
    con.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run
```

the data is input through a web form. Below is how the database is created.

```
import sqlite3

connection = sqlite3.connect('database.db')


with open('schema.sql') as f:
    connection.executescript(f.read())

cur = connection.cursor()


connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

The schema file:

```
CREATE TABLE bookings (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    email TEXT NOT NULL,
    created TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    booked_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
```

Comment: First of all post the full code, there's no imports there, so if the problem is in a line of code that you didn't post we won't be able to help.

Comment: Could be a circular import of the `__main__` module.

Comment: Why the `from flask import request` if it's not being used?

Comment: @Daviid two import lines added = full code

Comment: @Daviid a further module needed after the SQL query but I assure you I haven't got that far yet I am targeting the SQL query code

Comment: If that's the full code it's weird that you get 2 prints, can you add the bookins table create query to test locally?

Comment: @LiamW I've tried locally and couldn't reproduce the error. So it doesn't seem like a python error, maybe try `which python3` to see if that may be the problem?

Comment: That or try a simple python script like JUST `print("test")`, save it and execute that.

Comment: @Daviid print("test") works as expected and nothing unusual about which python. Please see further edits if they are of use

Answer (score 0):

```py
import sqlite3

SQLITE_SCRIPT = """
-- Create the bookings table
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bookings (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    email TEXT,
    booked_time DATETIME
);

-- Insert some sample data
INSERT INTO bookings (email, booked_time) VALUES
    ('user1@example.com', '2023-09-04 10:00:00'),
    ('user2@example.com', '2023-09-04 14:30:00'),
    ('user3@example.com', '2023-09-05 09:15:00');
"""

def read_query(query):
    con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
    # Write the downloaded data into the in-memory database
    con.executescript(SQLITE_SCRIPT)
    cur = con.cursor()

    cur.execute(query)
    result = cur.fetchall()
    return result


q1 = """
SELECT email,booked_time,strftime('%Y-%m-%d',booked_time) as 'date'
FROM bookings
WHERE date = DATE('2023-09-04');
"""

print(read_query(q1))
```

I tried this locally and didn't get a double print.
Instead of using a sqlite file I create an in memory database, create the table and insert some data. Can you try this and see if you get the same problem?

Edit: if it still happens I can only think to try from inside the python interpreter

Start it with
`devbox:~/web_app_project$ python3`

then

```py
import sqlite3
```

```py
SQLITE_SCRIPT = """
-- Create the bookings table
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bookings (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    email TEXT,
    booked_time DATETIME
);

-- Insert some sample data
INSERT INTO bookings (email, booked_time) VALUES
    ('user1@example.com', '2023-09-04 10:00:00'),
    ('user2@example.com', '2023-09-04 14:30:00'),
    ('user3@example.com', '2023-09-05 09:15:00');
"""
```

```py
def read_query(query):
    con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
    # Write the downloaded data into the in-memory database
    con.executescript(SQLITE_SCRIPT)
    cur = con.cursor()

    cur.execute(query)
    result = cur.fetchall()
    return result
```

```py
q1 = """
SELECT email,booked_time,strftime('%Y-%m-%d',booked_time) as 'date'
FROM bookings
WHERE date = DATE('2023-09-04');
"""
```

```py
print(read_query(q1))
```

Try copying and pasting block by block.